# Multiple builds on a Single Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have a bash script that calls three other bash scripts each dependent upon the execution of the previous script. Is there a way to run the three scripts with three individual build buttons instead of having just one build button for all the three scripts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are about, but here is my guess : you have three scripts, but you want to see each individual status ?

Jenkins job are meant to be self sufficient or based on input parameter or even linked.
There is no way to run sub part directly.

If you want to run one script on its own, you need to split your Jenkins job into 3 different jobs and link them *(ie : pushing parameter)*

Hope this helps
Regards